# Return always false as using isSelected() in Selenium Webdriver java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

I'm trying to use `isSelected()` method on Amazon website.

I'm trying to tick the check-box of item filter and then read the status of check-box by `isSelected()` but it always returns false message.

Please help me to overcome this problem.

```
package seleniumProgram;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.xml.LaunchSuite;

public class Check_isDisplayed_Enabled_Selected extends A_openBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        openChrome("www.amazon.com");
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
        
        System.out.println("Search box is Displayed = "+search.isDisplayed());
        System.out.println("Search box is Enabled = "+search.isEnabled());
        
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Nintendo+Switch+Games&i=videogames&bbn=16227133011&rh=n%3A16227133011&dc&ds=v1%3Au77TZDZ%2FgBsOBF9WBVz5WxCcRXqJa6CeSHU8sDYD8Dk&pf_rd_i=23508887011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=434db2ed-6d53-4c59-b173-e8cd550a2e4f&pf_rd_r=CVZSGC265EZ08YTW0ZDE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1653816583&rnid=2528832011&ref=sr_nr_p_89_1");
        
        WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']"));
        System.out.println("U&I Entertainment CheckBox is Selected = "+box.isSelected());
        
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
        WebElement clik = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/span[1]/a[1]/div[1]/label[1]/i[1]"));
        System.out.println("U&I Entertainment CheckBox is Selected = "+clik.isSelected());
        driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is to check if a check with the label "`U&I Entertainment`" is selected/checked/clicked.

But, in your code,

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']"));

WebElement clik = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/span[1]/a[1]/div[1]/label[1]/i[1]"));
```

you are actually getting an `<li>` element and not the actual `<input type="checkbox">` within that `<li>`.

So I changed those 2 lines with,

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']//input[@type='checkbox']"));

WebElement clik = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']//input[@type='checkbox']"));
```

and I got the desired result.

Here's my code that worked,

```
try {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
            
            System.out.println("Search box is Displayed = "+search.isDisplayed());
            System.out.println("Search box is Enabled = "+search.isEnabled());
            
            driver.navigate().to("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Nintendo+Switch+Games&i=videogames&bbn=16227133011&rh=n%3A16227133011&dc&ds=v1%3Au77TZDZ%2FgBsOBF9WBVz5WxCcRXqJa6CeSHU8sDYD8Dk&pf_rd_i=23508887011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=434db2ed-6d53-4c59-b173-e8cd550a2e4f&pf_rd_r=CVZSGC265EZ08YTW0ZDE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1653816583&rnid=2528832011&ref=sr_nr_p_89_1");
            
            WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            System.out.println("U&I Entertainment CheckBox is Selected = "+box.isSelected());
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']")).click();
            
            WebElement clik = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/U&I Entertainment']//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            System.out.println("Search box is Displayed = "+clik.isDisplayed());
            System.out.println("U&I Entertainment CheckBox is Selected = "+clik.isSelected());

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```